# Как посмотреть строку, которая будет сформирована в subprocess.Popen()?

Tags: python

Приветствую. Подскажите как посмотреть строку, которая будет сформирована в subprocess.Popen() из переданных параметров? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читаем официальную документацию - [pipeline](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) и используем функцию communicate.